# Check condition of SimpleDate converted string in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do a simple IF check of a String that I know has been formatted correctly with:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```

At this point formattedDate is "09/24/2015". I can confirm that this is true:

```
remoteViews.setTextViewText( R.id.widget_date, formattedDate);
```

It's showing me the correct date.  So I know it's good.
So I test it:

```
if (formattedDate=="09/24/2015"){
//do some stuff
}
```

For whatever reason, that condition is **not** true, and nothing happens.
I have tried everything from removing the slashes, to just changing the format around, but formattedDate never equals what that string clearly is.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.equals()` to compare Strings. Like this

```
if (formattedDate.equals("09/24/2015")){
    //do some stuff
}
```

`==` tests for "reference equality", so whether `a` and `b` are referencing the same object
`.equals(anotherObject)` tests for "value equality", whether `a` and `b` are logically equal

Comment: Seriously?!  (Not that I doubt you, because I've seen that before.  But why is that the case?  Why does == not work for this?  Please elaborate.

Comment: @durbnpoisn use your google-fu.

Comment: I did.  Except I was asking the wrong question.  I was running on the assumption that the conversion from the date was the problem.  I didn't think it was as simple as using the incorrect operator for comparison.  I have like 12 apps working and up on Google Play.  And never once had I run into this particular problem.  Not once.